# Self hosting components with bit.dev, error: Cannot find module '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, bit.dev

I am trying to self host components using bit.dev by following this article https://github.com/teambit/bit/discussions/4707
When I run bit start and I get this error:
Cannot find module '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\dist\extensions\ui\webpack\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\dist\extensions\ui\ui.extension.js
- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\dist\extensions\ui\index.js
- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\dist\extensions\bit\manifests.js
- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\dist\extensions\bit\bit.manifest.js
- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\dist\extensions\bit\index.js
- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\dist\app.js
- C:\Users\Ruben Peters\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bit-bin\bin\bit.js

I have tried to install this '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin' which the error says it can not find, I then tried to run bit start again and I still get the same error. Help please

Comment: can you please add more details? when are you getting this errors? also note that there's a docker container now that can help speed up the process.